# VBA click HTML Dropdown List Item

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation

I'm trying to develop a spreadsheet that will load webpage and interact with it. I have been able to load the website, login and click some buttons.

However I can't seem to click the "Enter Time" from the "Action" dropdown using the same method.

I have attached the InspectElement code & the VBA snippet below.

Can anyone advise how to do this?

Many Thanks

```
Sub Uploader()

'-- Create instance for IE Object & Navigate to Website
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://somewebsite.com"
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop           'Wait until page has loaded
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    
'-- Loop button tags and click Actions Dropdown
    Call Click_HTML_Element("button", "Actions", "2")  'This Works
    Call Click_HTML_Element("div", "Enter Time", "1")  'This doesnt work
'    Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
'    Application.SendKeys "{Enter}"
    
End Sub


Function Click_HTML_Element(Element As String, Tag As String, WaitTime As String)
  
    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(Element)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:0" & WaitTime))
    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    For Each ButtonTag In HTMLButtons
        If Left(ButtonTag.innerText, Len(Tag)) = Tag Then
            ButtonTag.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ButtonTag

End Function
```

The HTML i'm trying to target is below:

```
<div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR"
 id="c89dcac376424796940e75cef5f53ea6" 
role="option" aria-selected="false" 
aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="7" 
data-automation-id="dropdown-option" 
data-automation-label="Enter Time" 
data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Enter Time</div></li>
```

which sits in this larger bit of HTML

```
<div class="WJT wd-popup-content" style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; max-height: 256px; max-width: 457px;">
    <ul tabindex="0" class="WOKR WDLR WENR" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="27a2ea69ab524009a23e565a58e32c91" aria-activedescendant="03040a5694c04547a26cf3484959f7ca" data-automation-id="menuList">
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR WHKR" id="03040a5694c04547a26cf3484959f7ca" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Clear" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Clear</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="c89dcac376424796940e75cef5f53ea6" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Enter Time" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Enter Time</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="112d644689034ea38a105e3ee70c73b8" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="3" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Enter Time by Type" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Enter Time by Type</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="240144742b98490b8297bc1c80f021c9" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="4" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Quick Add" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Quick Add</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="1c21796b32c0494799e6ea26c338f27b" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="5" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Request Absence" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Request Absence</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="acb4b118051a43038e355dbaee00a323" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="6" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Review Time by Week" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Review Time by Week</div>
        </li>
        <li class="WCLR" role="presentation">
            <div tabindex="-2" class="WIKR WEKR WKJR WBLR WPKR" id="21c608d18ba040eab12f1431ab243d11" role="option" aria-selected="false" aria-posinset="7" aria-setsize="7" data-automation-id="dropdown-option" data-automation-label="Run Calculations" data-automation-dropdown-option="dropdown-option">Run Calculations</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't suppose you can share the URL? Working w/ IE in VBA took me a long time to get "good" with lol, I can see some issues already, like always try to avoid `SENDKEYS`. I'd think you want to set the `VALUE` of this DropDown, not `Click` It.

Comment: FYI, `functions` should return a value like `As String` at the end. A `Sub` DOES something like `Click`.

Comment: `HTMLDoc.getElementById("c89dcac376424796940e75cef5f53ea6").Click` would work to click the DropDown, if thats what you wanted, but I suspect you may want to set the `.Value`

Comment: Looks like this might not be public facing and free to access. However, if it is, please share the url.

Comment: What does happen with the failing click? Also, is a pop-up involved and does a parent element have to remain visible in order to make a child selection? I would also prefer a css attribute = value selector in this case over targeting the .innerText.